# How do I make this little PHP Array work?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I want to find out how I can store small strings in an array and output them correct.
In this case I want to set a two-letter language code in an array at the top and 
then output a string in that language later.

I really appreciate your help.

The following code I've made does not work but it's something like this I'm looking for:

```
<?php

// Set the language
$settings = array(
  Language => "en"
);

// Set the strings
$locales = array(
  Installed => array("en", "da"),
  TheString => array("Dog", "Hund")
);

// Do some magic
$lang = $settings["Language"][0];

// Output Dog (or Hund if the language is "da")
echo $lang["TheString"];

?>
```

Comment: You may have made this as convoluted as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$settings = array( 'lanaguage' => 'en');

$locales = array( 
    'en' => array(
        'dog' => 'dog'
    ),
    'da' => array(
        'dog' => 'hund'
    )
);

// You don't need this, but you can get it like so:
$installed_languages = array_keys( $locales); 

echo $locales[ $settings['language'] ]['dog'];
```

This will either output `dog` if `$settings['language']` is `en`, or `hund` if it is `da`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that experienced.
Thanks for your answer! I guess I can create a variable like

$lang = $locales[ $settings['language'] ];

and then 

echo $lang ['dog'];

because then it will be less messy with a lot of strings.
I will test it now.

Comment: The code provided by nickb works perfect. Since I have under 10 points I cannot close this question until after 7 hours.

Comment: Nice answer! Good use of arrays.